# check continuity of a number series using if-else

Tags: shell, if-statement, awk, fortran

I have a file which contain numbers, say 1 to 300. But the numbers are not continuous. A sample file looks like this

```
042
043
044
045
078
198
199
200
201
202
203
212
213
214
215
238
239
240
241
242
256
257
258
```

Now I need to check the continuity of the number series and accordingly write out the output. For example the first 4 numbers are in series, so the output should be

```
042-045
```

Next, 078 is a lone number, so the output should be

```
078
```

for convenience it can be made to look like

```
078-078
```

Then 198 to 203 are continuous. So, next output should be

```
198-203
```

and so on. The final output should be like

```
042-045
078-078
198-203
212-215
238-242
256-258
```

I just need to know the first and end member of the continuous series and jump on the next series when discontinuity is encountered; The output can be manipulated. I am inclined to use the if statement and can think of a complicated thing like this

```
    num=`cat file | wc -l`
    out1=`head -1 file`
    for ((i=2;i<=$num;i++))
    do
     j=`echo $i-1 | bc`
     var1=`cat file | awk 'NR='$j'{print}'`
     var2=`cat file | awk 'NR='$i'{print}'`
     var3=`echo $var2 - $var1 | bc`
     if [ $var3 -gt 1 ]
     then 
      out2=$var1
      echo $out1-$out2
      out1=$var2
     fi
    done
```

which works but too lengthy. I am sure there is definitely a short way of doing this. 
I am also open to other straight-forward command (or few commands) in shell, awk or a few lines of fortran code that can do it.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This awk one-liner works for given example:

```
awk 'p+1!=$1{printf "%s%s--",NR==1?"":p"\n",$1}{p=$1}END{print $1}' file
```

It gives the output for your data as input:

```
042--045
078--078
198--203
212--215
238--242
256--258
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kent. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple program in Fortran:

```
program test
  implicit none
  integer :: first, last, uFile, i, stat

  open( file='numbers.txt', newunit=uFile, action='read', status='old' )
  read(uFile,*,iostat=stat) i
  if ( stat /= 0 ) stop

  first = i ; last = i
  do 
    read(uFile,*,iostat=stat) i
    if ( stat /= 0 ) exit

    if ( i == last+1 ) then
      last = i
    else 
      print *,first,'-',last
      write(*,'(i3.3,a,i3.3)') first,'-',last
    endif
  enddo 
  write(*,'(i3.3,a,i3.3)') first,'-',last
end program
```

The output is

```
042-045
078-078
198-203
212-215
238-242
256-258
```

Comment: @HimangshuPaul You don't have to thank in the comments although the posters probably appreciate it. It is customary here to select one answer and mark it as accepted if it solved your problem. It is up to you which one and if any at all you choose.